# Zoho Recruit API Register / Login Candidate

Tags: api, authentication, zoho

Could someone guide me an idea of how to create the registration and login for candidates with the Recruit api? I'm making a flutter app and I need my candidates to register and log in trow the app and see the job opening, post jobs.

At the moment I created the user with [POST] https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/v2/Candidates

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Email": "mail@gmail.com",
        "First_Name": "TheName",
        "Last_Name": "TheLastName",
        "Mobile": "000000000",
        "Expected_Salary": "8000000",
        "Country": "PY",
        "Departamento": "Central",
        "C_I": "37114594",
        "Ciudad_de_residencia": "City",
        "$Password":"myPassWord199**"
    }
],
"trigger": [
    "approval",
    "workflow",
    "blueprint"
]
```

}

Works Well, got success

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "code": "SUCCESS",
        "details": {
            "Modified_Time": "2022-06-15T20:47:23-04:00",
            "Modified_By": {
                "name": "Admin",
                "id": "00000000000000"
            },
            "Created_Time": "2022-06-15T20:47:23-04:00",
            "id": "00000000000000",
            "Created_By": {
                "name": "Admin",
                "id": "00000000000000"
            }
        },
        "message": "record added",
        "status": "success"
    }
]
}
```

But If I try to log in in the web version (for testing the new candidate) don't work, but if it see the dashboard, the user exist. Need to add something else?

Basically I need a register api and a login one for the created record of the candidate.

Any help will be awesome, Thanks